# Why is DBMS_CRYPTO inaccessible for most users by default?

Tags: oracle, encryption

Oracle's [`DBMS_CRYPTO`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_crypto.htm#ARPLS664) package is [locked down by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34808544/1394393). Very few users have permissions on it; the only ones on my database are `SYSMAN`, `OWBSYS`, and `APEX_030200`. (Of course the owning `SYS` has privileges, too.) These notably don't include even the default `SYSTEM` account. The documentation states

> Oracle Database installs this package in the `SYS` schema. You can then grant package access to existing users and roles as needed.

in the "Security Model" section, so the behavior is documented as normal.

But what I don't understand is *why*. I could not locate any information about the reason behind this default either in the package's documentation or [the guide on using it](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/data_encryption.htm). Is there some risk that these functions pose? Would granting access to `PUBLIC` be a bad idea for some reason?

Answer (score 1):

A fundamental principle of Oracle security is everything is prohibited unless specifically granted.  You see this even in creating a new user.  Unless you specifically grant them CREATE SESSION (or a role that includes it) they can't even log on, even with proper credentials.  There is no reason grant execute on that package by default.  And keep in mind that there is really nothing "special" about SYSTEM.  It is just a default DBA user.  Also consider that DBMS_CRYPTO is of more use (in general) to apps developers, so why should it break the Principle of Least Privilege by making effectively available to everyone?

Comment: I'm not sure this makes sense as an explanation. `PUBLIC` has privileges to execute 220 of the 622 packages owned by `SYS`, over 1/3. They include `UTL_FILE`, `DBMS_STATS`, `UTL_TCP`, `UTL_COMPRESS`, `DBMS_CUBE`, and `DBMS_JAVA`. Most users will have no need to access files, statistics, TCP, compression, data cubes, or interact with Java, especially if they don't even own the objects they're accessing. By Least Privilege, shouldn't these be locked down as well? Or is there some reason over 200 packages should be exposed to `PUBLIC`?

Comment: Well, that was _my_ best guess :-)  I guess if you want an authoritative reason why the software engineers at oracle make the design decisions they do, you'd have to ask them.  Perhaps someone else will offer a more satisfying answer.  However, unless an oracle engineer weighs in, someone else's opinion  will simply be _their_ best guess -  but I'd be willing to accept it if they present a more compelling case than mine.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate it. It just doesn't seem to match the evidence. I suppose my hope was that it's documented somewhere not easy to find or that others have discussed it on blogs I haven't been able to find, and that someone who's been working with Oracle for longer might have seen it.